# Extracting a value from a file name base on regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, filenames

Suppose my file name pattern is something like this `%#_Report_%$_for_%&.xls` and `%#` and `%$` regex can have any character but `%&` is a date.

Now how can i get the actual values of those regex on filename in java.

For example if actual filename is `Genr_Report_123_for_20151105.xls` how to get

```
%# value is Genr
%$ value is 123
%& value is 20151105
```

Comment: file regex is %#_Report_%$_for_%&.xls

Comment: Use `"^([^_]+)_Report_([^_]+)_for_([^._]+)\.xls$"` and use capturing groups.

Comment: can you help me in writing code for this

Comment: I would ask you what you've tried but it seems that the clear answer is nothing. [@anubhava has given you the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549948/extracting-a-value-from-a-file-name-base-on-regex-in-java#comment54879537_33549948). If you make an attempt at implementing and it doesn't work, post it in the question and I will help you out.

Comment: i have tried matchers and patterns, but i am not able to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Rgx {

    private String str1 = "", str2 = "", date = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "Genr_Report_123_for_20151105.xls";

        Rgx rgx = new Rgx();
        rgx.extractValues(fileName);
        System.out.println(rgx.str1 + " " + rgx.str2 + " " + rgx.date);
    }

    private void extractValues(String fileName) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([^_]+)_Report_([^_]+)_for_([\\d]+)\\.xls");
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(fileName);

        if (m.find()) {
            str1 = m.group(1);
            str2 = m.group(2);
            date = m.group(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply,